# Multi-Thread BufferedReader for reading .txt

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedreader

I'm wanting to read the line of a .txt do the task, and move on to the next line.

To make the program quicker, I want to multi-thread so each thread tries a line.

The problem is, I don't want the thread 1 trying the same line as thread 2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let each thread skip *x* lines, with *x* being the number of threads; or just use a shared `Scanner/FileReader/StringReader` and call `nextLine()` or similar. Make sure to lock that `Scanner` each time you read a line so that you do not encounter two read accesses at the same time.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic:  Why do you think making this multi-threaded will be quicker?

Comment: Your code will be I/O bound, not CPU bound, so multi-threading will not improve performance.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you have *one* thread doing all the reading, then put the lines into a producer/consumer queue (e.g. a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)) - you can then have multiple threads servicing that queue as consumers.

You really don't want multiple threads performing IO here - even if you had multiple independent `BufferedReaders`, if you're reading from traditional disks you don't want to end up seeking in multiple places. A producer/consumer queue separates the reading from the handling fairly simply - and makes it easier to test each part in isolation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the lines in one thread and dispatch a worker thread for each line:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my.txt"))) {
   String line;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     new Runnable() {
        void run() {
           // do stuff with line
        }
     }.run();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea on what you are trying to achieve but not sure how you will code it.
If you can make each thread work on a different set of lines then the threads will not clash.
I mean let thread1 read from 1 to 100, thread2 read from 101 to 200 and so on.
At the end join the results of all the threads to get the final result.
Maybe a Fork/Join operation.

But @Jon comment makes me wary of following such an approach.

"You really don't want multiple threads performing IO here - even if you had multiple independent BufferedReaders, if you're reading from traditional disks you don't want to end up seeking in multiple places..